# Need to extract Sub-Tree of XML, before processing with XSLT Processor

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I'm processing a XML with XSL with PHP to a HTML output. So far, so good. Here's my code.

```
<?php

$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load("content.xsl");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("content.xml");

    // some xpath/dom-query filtering to get 
    // subtree of loaded xml-file

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);

?>
```

Like you can see, this is a simple XSLT Processor. The output works well. For example I have in the given XML three sibling nodes "node":

```
<root>
 <node>
  <subnode>..</subnode>
 </node>
 <node>
  <subnode>..</subnode>
 </node>
 <node>
  <subnode>..</subnode>
 </node>
</root>
```

Now I want just pass the second node through the XML Processor.

How can I do this?

chris

Comment: Can I ask why you need to extract the node before passing it to the XSLT rather than using the XSLT to extract it?

Comment: I want to know how both approaches work. I already know the way through XSLT and extract it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my task by my own - but thank you for your application.

Here is my code:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xmlDoc->load("content.xml");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$query = '//ContentData/Content[1]/Headline';
$nodeList = $xpath->query($query);


$newDom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$root = $newDom->createElement('root');
$root = $newDom->appendChild($root);


foreach ($nodeList as $domElement){
   $domNode = $newDom->importNode($domElement, true);
   $root->appendChild($domNode);
}

$newDom->saveXML();


$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load("content.xsl");

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);

echo $proc->transformToXML($newDom);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtodoc.php, the `transformToDoc` method takes any DOM node as its argument so you could access `$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('node')->item(1)` and pass that to `transformToDoc` and then use `saveXML` or `saveHTML` to get a string of XML or HTML, depending on what kind of result you are looking for.